# bootstrap 3 navbar collapse not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I have implemented the bootstrap nav bar on my MVC layout view and the collapse menu dosent seem work all of a sudden. Not able to spot the issue. It was working before. Not sure if it is because of some css rule that has messed up

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/custom/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body >

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#"><img src="~/Images/Computacenter.png" /> </a>
                    <h1>MCR</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Home</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Requests</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Activities</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Reports</p></a></li>
                        <li class="hideli"><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Admin</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Save View</p></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <div id="body">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>


     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-top: none;
    background-image: url('../../Images/iNeed__waterfall_BG.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#body {
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 82px;
    background: transparent;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-header img {
    max-height: 55px;
    max-width: 55px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.navbar-header h1 {
    float: left;
    color: darkblue;
}


/*.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top:0px;
}*/


.nav navbar-nav navbar-right {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: add `bootstrap js` after `jQuery` before `</body>` tag

Comment: I added in the following sequence but yet not working

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Comment: How its works `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false) `and why you use it?

Comment: the required indicates whether or not the view using the layout page must have a scripts section.IN SHORT, when set to true, whether you need it or not on other pages, it will get rendered anyhow. If set to false, it will render only when the child page is rendered.

Comment: Checkout **code** carefully! If there any kind of **Markup** syntax missing because of *syntax* missing will not JS rendering and show console error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137667/discussion-between-md-abdul-momin-and-tom).